# MySQL query in NodeJS returning current_timestamp as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.0000Z

Tags: mysql, node.js, timestamp, timezone, mysql-workbench

I have a table named `inpatient` inside a MySQL schema. The table has a column `admit_date` which automatically generates a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and stores it in the column when a record is created. 
 
[image]

The picture shown above is of that column inside my MySQL Workbench. It is storing the correct value. Now the problem arises when I query this date inside NodeJS. If I write a simple query as: 
`SELECT admit_date from inpatient`, 
I get the following data as a result:

```
[
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T23:46:43.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T23:46:43.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T23:46:43.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T22:53:21.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T22:53:21.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T22:53:21.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T22:53:21.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T22:53:21.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T22:53:21.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T22:53:21.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-03T22:53:21.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { admit_date: 2021-05-06T00:57:01.000Z }
]
```

Is this problem NodeJs specific because it seems like so. Anyways, is there any way i could format this somewhat unreadable value or if i could write a new statement that fetches me the correct value stored in the schema? My goal is to get the timestamp exactly as it is in the `admit_date` column.

Comment: It is possible that the MySQL timestamps are in UTC format, but your data as seen from Node is in your local timezone.  What is your exact goal here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Edited! I want the data exactly as it is in the `admit_date` column.

Comment: What is the "correct value"? Storing date-times as UTC is a good practice. Convert as necessary to someone's local time zone in your client-side code.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, `TIMESTAMP` data types are always stored in UTC time.  They're stored in an internal format.  When retrieved, two things happpen. They are

- converted to the current session's time zone, and
- converted to the `2021-04-01 12:34:556` text rendering.

If you want them converted to a particular time-zone, issue this sort of MySQL command in your connection before doing your SELECT.

```
SET time_zone='Asia/Kolkata';
```

or whatever time zone you need.

If you don't want this UTC and timezone functionality use MySQL's `DATETIME` data type in place of `TIMESTAMP`.

If you're doing hospital IT in the USA, you DO want this timezone functionality because of [Medicare's notorious three-midnight rule](https://www.cms.gov/Outreach-and-Education/Medicare-Learning-Network-MLN/MLNProducts/Downloads/SNF3DayRule-MLN9730256.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

By default, MySQL driver for Node.js will convert `Date` and `DateTime` fields into plain `Date()` object, you should be able to use any available methods that it provides

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

In case if you need to format it into something more readable consider using libraries like moment, dayjs, date-fns which provide simple ways to perform conversions

You also can override default behaviour by changing `typeCast` parameter of database connection, for example, setting it to false will disable type casting completley

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#type-casting